# 500 error during list request

Tags: google-drive-api

Started getting 500 error when trying to execute `gapi.client.drive.files.list`, even using the API exprorer.

Authorization works fine.

request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

response:

```
500 Internal Server Error

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  66
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 28 Mar 2013 01:24:28 GMT
expires:  Thu, 28 Mar 2013 01:24:28 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

It was working yesterday.

**Update**

Apparently it works if I limit the result set to **19** (no query string) or **13** (*q: 'root' in parents*)

I guess Google developers introduced some kind of limit yesterday?
Or may be I have an invalid file entry which started chrashing the google server?

How can I investigate?

Thanks!